# How to identify the process which has loaded a certain file

Tags: windows, process, pid

I have certain file in the disk which I am unable to delete, as it mentions that it's being used by a certain process.

How do I identify the process which is using this file?

Answer (score 1):

Open [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), use the "Find handle" button.

Another popular tool is [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml).

Comment: It's so weird, the Process explorer doesn't seem to identify the process which uses a certain mysql jdbc jar file.